# Dynamic Applications And Translation

Tags: language, dynamic-ui

We are developing a multi-language web software. We allow end user to create applications dynamically.

**Scenario:** Say we need a "sales app (we call modules as app)" which requires following fields:

Sales Description, Due Date and Total Amount.

End-user is eligable to create this app by himself. (He gives a name to app, drags fields into creation form (in modify mode). And saves the app)

**My problem is multi-language.** We provide base apps to users by default. But these base apps also have the *dynamic creation* approach.

I would like to present names of the *base apps* in default language of the system. Although these base apps have dynamic creation approach, we create these apps before delivering product to users for providing a system logic to users. But I am not sure if my claim is true or not. Should I present names in default language? What do you suggest me to do? What is the best UX solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime giving a personal touch to any application is a great Idea. While designing any application for the user (web or software) the initial design should not focus more on the implementation, but it does not mean that you should totally ignore the implementation. Coming back to what you asked, if the base app uses terminology that justifies the intent of the different elements you use than undoubtedly you should go with the default language of the system. But if the change in language will also change the actual semantic or meaning of the element used in base app than changing to default language can be a problem.
For example, if you are using a word 'X' that has meaning 'Y' and in any language you changed 'X' to 'Z'. Now if 'Z' has the same meaning as 'Y' than its fine to change to default language ('Z' is the default language) but if 'Z' change to something  other than 'Y' than it is not a good idea.

Now comes the implementation part, if you go with the change to default language option than you should confirm with the developer team about the feasibility of the idea

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes perfect sense to present the user with something in their own language. It will make them much more comfortable using, exploring, and learning your system.